# Allow float value in Input

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to Allow float value in Input.When i am trying to input float value decimal (.) not able to enter.
Example: 143.52, 178.30, 3658.20 etc..
http://jsfiddle.net/vLEZY/75/

```
 <input type="text" onkeypress='return validateQty(event);'>


<script
    function validateQty(event) {
        var key = window.event ? event.keyCode : event.which;
        if (event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39) {
            return true;
        } else if (key < 48 || key > 57) {
            return false;
        } else return true;
    };

</script>
```

Comment: Your first `if` test involves `event.keyCode` even though you've gone to the trouble of feature-detecting whether it's that or `event.which`.

Comment: @mccainz do not copy paste value. just enter with KB 145.30 . then look decimal (.) is not entering.

Comment: Prefer the use of change event and format number...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/mcg0x0hh/2/

```
if (event.keyCode == 8 || key == 46 || event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39)
```

I modified event.keyCode in key for the code 46, which is the dot. I would change all event.keyCode to key, unless you have a good reason to keep them like that.